# Why isn't this only removing the dataframes with Nan values on last line?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The point of this loop is to put all coins above the 'SMA200' in a list.  I'm trying to filter out any data with Nan values in the last line of the dataframe. But the line `if df.iloc[-1:].any(None):` is not catching what I expect it to catch. Could anyone help?

```
bullish_coins =[]
with open('Binance_USDT.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        if "," not in line:
            continue
        symbol = line.split(",")[0]
        strip = line.split(",")[1]
        bars =binance.fetch_ohlcv(symbol, timeframe =timeframe, limit=limit)
        df =pd.DataFrame(bars, columns=['timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
        df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
        df["SMA200"] = df['close'].rolling(window=200).mean()
        if df.iloc[-1:].any(None):
            print(df)
            df.dropna(inplace=True)
        elif int(df['close'][-1:]) >= int(df['SMA200'][-1:]):
            bullish_coins.append(symbol)
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: Try `df.iloc[-1:].isnull().values.any()`

Comment: I've trying to figure this out all day.  Thanks, that worked!